# python: polySplitRing Insert with Edge flow on multiple edges

Tags: python, maya, mel

I'm a real Python noob (been playing with it for about a week now) but I'm really enjoying streamlining some of my Maya tools. I'm currently a little stuck on the following;
I am trying to get polySplitRing with Insert with Edge Flow to work on a selection of multiple edges. I can get it to work on one edge, but I can't get it to work on multiple edges. I'm trying to use a list, but I need something mo better than that. Have tried searching for the same problem but didn't find anything (also not sure what to search for exactly). If there's a doc for setting something like this up, pls link!

Here's what works fine on a single edge selection:
single edge selection:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel as mm

mm.eval("polySelectSp -ring;")
cmds.polySplitRing(ief=True, cch=1)
```

Here's what I'm working at for multiple edge solution

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel as mm

sel=cmds.ls(sl=1)
edgeCount = cmds.polyEvaluate(ec=True)
print edgeCount
edgeList = [edgeCount]
print edgeList

for each in edgeList:
    mm.eval("polySelectSp -ring;")
    cmds.polySplitRing(ief=True, cch=1)


mm.eval("polySelectSp -ring;")
cmds.polySplitRing(ief=True, cch=1)
```

[polySplitEdgeRing Insert with Edge Flow working on a single edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NONT0.jpg)

[desired end result after selecting multiple edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPqae.jpg)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't especially need to use mel module, you can do the same operations in Python (better).

Then, just create a list of selected edges and apply your split on each one.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

selEdges = cmds.ls(selection = True)

for edge in selEdges:
    # Find edge Id
    edgeId = int(edge.split('[')[-1][:-1]) # Should be better with a regex, I know...
    # Apply split on this particular edge thanks to edge Id
    cmds.polySelect(edgeRing = edgeId)
    cmds.polySplitRing(ief = True)
```